# Is there a plist editor available as an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: iphone, eclipse, plist

I am a mobile apps developer currently working on most of my projects out of Xcode, but have the need to use Eclipse for various tasks, such as XML editing. I have created a lightweight version of Eclipse with only a handful of plugins, which have so far been very helpful. I am currently looking to see if there is a plist editor for Eclipse (visual, not xml-based). Is there anything currently available? If not, I may attempt to add one myself. Does anyone know of any open-source plist editors that could be used for this purpose?